# How to store binary data in SQLite tables with FTS3 enabled?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, fts3

I'm transitioning an application from using a normal SQLite database to one with full text search enabled. It has several BLOB columns that store things like digital signatures, which obviously do not need to be indexed. I've read that other people solve this by moving all non-TEXT data to a separate, non-FTS3 table that they inner join with the FTS3 table when necessary, but this is a very inelegant solution. Is there no way to simply exclude certain columns from indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not inelegant. SQL is relational, joins are a natural part of life. Thinking they're "inelegant" is what leads to stereotypically poor database designs.

You've determined you have two different kinds of data -- text you often need to search, and blobs you do not. There is absolutely nothing wrong or inelegant about storing these in two different tables.

Comment: I call it inelegant because normal tables allow data of different types to coexist without having to maintain different tables that you have to constantly keep in sync with each other. That is simply not elegant. I will probably have to completely reengineer my application. Or at least, that is how I take it from reading your answer.

Comment: @oskar: If you have to completely reengineer your application in order to change your database layout, you're using the database _very_ wrong. Splitting a few columns off into a separate table is an extremely common thing to do, and should be a quick and painless change in any well-designed application.

Comment: I need to reengineer it in the sense they every SELECT statement I currently have will have to be changed to include a join to another table, every INSERT will have to be changed to insert into two separate tables, and every DELETE will have to be changed to delete from two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it less of a hassle by creating a view of the join that you can then select over. You can still use MATCH on the columns that originated in the fts table, and you don't have to do that join every time you want to query.